# Algorithm video tutorial

Tags: algorithm, video

There are quite a few algorithm lectures on the web, but what I'm looking for is a video tutorial where I can watch somebody coding on screen, going from a blank document to an algorithm that solves a problem. Language doesn't really matter. There are lots of video tutorials like this about a certain language, but is there one that teaches an algorithm?

Comment: I've never seen it too, maybe because algorithm is not an art form, or skill is not how you construct it but how you imagine it, its more to iterative logic that involves trial and error, scratch pad, dreaming the code, etc. it would be so boring to see such video. just my thought.

Comment: yes, just like when I'm in Mathematics class. The teacher teach us by solving the problem from scratch, step by step, most of the times with trial and error and explaining it along the way.  I would like to see this kind of teaching in algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Conway's [Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) coded in one line of [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29) is pretty good. The video starts from a blank screen and builds the code up live in the interpreter. Although it's a specific problem, the steps in involved in the construction are very instructive. I thought it was an amazing demo.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=GB&hl=en-GB&v=a9xAKttWgP4&fmt=18

Comment: this is one is pretty good, is there more like it ? preferably in mainstream language like java ,C# or python

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend the [Introduction to Algorithms video lecture series](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-046JFall-2005/VideoLectures/index.htm) by Charles Leiserson, the **L** of the standard Algorithms textbook, [CLRS](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=8570). He works out several fundamental algorithms in pseudocode.